# How can I modify a Smith and Waterman perl script to go faster?

Tags: algorithm, perl, alignment, bioinformatics

I found this perl script but I have too much sequences to analyze. I want to know if it is possible to optimize it? I launched NYTProf on it and saw the parts "calculate match score", "calculate gap scores" and "choose best score" take lots of time. Do I have to modify the data structure? Thank you for your help.

The perl script with the reference:

```
    # Smith-Waterman  Algorithm
# from this website http://etutorials.org/Misc/blast/Part+II+Theory/Chapter+3.+Sequence+Alignment/3.2+Local+Alignment+Smith-Waterman/

# Smith-Waterman  Algorithm

# usage statement
die "usage: $0 <sequence 1> <sequence 2>\n" unless @ARGV == 2;

# get sequences from command line
my ($seq1, $seq2) = @ARGV;

# scoring scheme
my $MATCH    =  1; # +1 for letters that match
my $MISMATCH = -1; # -1 for letters that mismatch
my $GAP      = -1; # -1 for any gap

# initialization
my @matrix;
$matrix[0][0]{score}   = 0;
$matrix[0][0]{pointer} = "none";
for(my $j = 1; $j <= length($seq1); $j++) {
    $matrix[0][$j]{score}   = 0;
    $matrix[0][$j]{pointer} = "none";
}
for (my $i = 1; $i <= length($seq2); $i++) {
    $matrix[$i][0]{score}   = 0;
    $matrix[$i][0]{pointer} = "none";
}

# fill
my $max_i     = 0;
my $max_j     = 0;
my $max_score = 0;

for(my $i = 1; $i <= length($seq2); $i++) {
    for(my $j = 1; $j <= length($seq1); $j++) {
        my ($diagonal_score, $left_score, $up_score);

        # calculate match score
        my $letter1 = substr($seq1, $j-1, 1);
        my $letter2 = substr($seq2, $i-1, 1);
        if ($letter1 eq $letter2) {
            $diagonal_score = $matrix[$i-1][$j-1]{score} + $MATCH;
        }
        else {
            $diagonal_score = $matrix[$i-1][$j-1]{score} + $MISMATCH;
        }

        # calculate gap scores
        $up_score   = $matrix[$i-1][$j]{score} + $GAP;
        $left_score = $matrix[$i][$j-1]{score} + $GAP;

        if ($diagonal_score <= 0 and $up_score <= 0 and $left_score <= 0) {
            $matrix[$i][$j]{score}   = 0;
            $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} = "none";
            next; # terminate this iteration of the loop
        }

        # choose best score
        if ($diagonal_score >= $up_score) {
            if ($diagonal_score >= $left_score) {
                $matrix[$i][$j]{score}   = $diagonal_score;
                $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} = "diagonal";
            }
            else {
                $matrix[$i][$j]{score}   = $left_score;
                $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} = "left";
            }
        } else {
            if ($up_score >= $left_score) {
                $matrix[$i][$j]{score}   = $up_score;
                $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} = "up";
            }
            else {
                $matrix[$i][$j]{score}   = $left_score;
                $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} = "left";
            }
        }

        # set maximum score
        if ($matrix[$i][$j]{score} > $max_score) {
            $max_i     = $i;
            $max_j     = $j;
            $max_score = $matrix[$i][$j]{score};
        }
    }
}

# trace-back

my $align1 = "";
my $align2 = "";

my $j = $max_j;
my $i = $max_i;

while (1) {
    last if $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} eq "none";

    if ($matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} eq "diagonal") {
        $align1 .= substr($seq1, $j-1, 1);
        $align2 .= substr($seq2, $i-1, 1);
        $i--; $j--;
    }
    elsif ($matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} eq "left") {
        $align1 .= substr($seq1, $j-1, 1);
        $align2 .= "-";
        $j--;
    }
    elsif ($matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} eq "up") {
        $align1 .= "-";
        $align2 .= substr($seq2, $i-1, 1);
        $i--;
    }
}

$align1 = reverse $align1;
$align2 = reverse $align2;
print "$align1\n";
print "$align2\n";
```

Comment: Rewrite it in C? It is already written very much in the "C-style of Perl", and it doesn't use any Perlish idioms that would be difficult to translate to C.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but unfortunately, I am not a C programmer!

Comment: Use an existing implementation of S-W that is written in C? Why do you have to use this specific script?

Comment: You are right, it is a good idea. In fact, I have another perl script which run this script and parse the results. But I can also call a C script! Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to avoid to do same things over and over again.

1. Instead of cutting single characters out of your sequences, you could try to split the sequence in chars once before the loops and than use the most likely faster access via index.

   Example:

   ```
   my $string = "Hello, how are you?";
   my @chars = split //, $string;  # Or: unpack 'a*', $string
   print "Eighth char: $chars[7]\n";
   ```
2. `my $letter2 = substr($seq2, $i-1, 1);` can go to the outer loop because `j` never changes in the inner loop.

   ```
   for(my $i = 1; $i <= length($seq2); $i++) {
       my $letter2 = substr($seq2, $i-1, 1);
       for(my $j = 1; $j <= length($seq1); $j++) {
   ```
3. Avoid the slower and complex C-style loop.

   ```
   for my $i (1..length($seq2)) {
       my $letter2 = substr($seq2, $i-1, 1);
       for my $j (1..length($seq1)) {
   ```
4. Instead of a string, use integers for the values of `pointer`. You can use constants to keep it readable.

   ```
   use constant {
      POINTER_NONE => 0,
      POINTER_LEFT => 1,
      ...
   };
   ```
5. Pre-calculating `$j-1` and `$i-1` may also bring a small advantage.

**Be aware** you should profile your code **before and after** each change to see if speed increases.

All of these are minor improvements. The real issue is that you have a quadratic algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. ABout your second point, I will try to work on it. But what do you mean about precalculating `$j-1`?

Comment: Do `my $jm1 = $j - 1;`, then use `$jm1` instead of `$j - 1`. I think the savings here will be noise. A better idea might be to use `for my $i (0..length($seq2)-1)` instead of `for my $i (1..length($seq2))`.

Comment: @MrSmith42, I hope you don't mind my additions. Feel free to revert if you do.

Comment: Re "*The real issue is that you have a quadratic algorithm.*", The algorithm is a variation of the dynamic approach of solving the Longest Common Substring problem. You can't do better than that. (That said, while it's O(N * M) processing time, it finds *all* solutions in that time, not just one.) I think its possible to reduce the *memory* used by that code, but I don't see a way of reducing the *processing time* in a significant way.

Comment: Ok, thank you ikegami for your advice. I am not sure how I can reduce the time of my analysis but I will use all of your comments. Maybe I can try to work on the script which call this one to parse my file. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is that you have a quadratic algorithm. It's inherently going to be slow. However, the algorithm is a variation of the dynamic approach of solving the Longest Common Substring problem, and you can't do better than that.

That said, here's an implementation that has the following features:

- Reduces the amount of memory from O(M*N) to O(M+N).
- Returns all possible solutions (at no extra cost!!!).
- Should be as fast as possible in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub local_alignment {
   my ($s, $t, %scheme) = @_;

   my $empty = [];

   my $MATCH    = $scheme{ MATCH    } // +1;  # Must be >= 1   # /
   my $MISMATCH = $scheme{ MISMATCH } // -1;  # Must be <= 0   # /
   my $GAP      = $scheme{ GAP      } // -1;  # Must be <= 0   # /

   my $m = my @s = unpack('(a)*', $s);
   my $n = my @t = unpack('(a)*', $t);

   my @best_score_at_k = ( 0      ) x (1+$m+$n);
   my @best_paths_at_k = ( $empty ) x (1+$m+$n);
   my $offset          = 1+$m;

   my $best_score = 0;
   my @best_paths;

   for my $i (0..$m-1) {
      --$offset;

      for my $j (0..$n-1) {
         my $k = $j + $offset;

         my $diag_score = $best_score_at_k[$k] + ( $s[$i] eq $t[$j] ? $MATCH : $MISMATCH );
         my $up_score   = $best_score_at_k[$k+1] + $GAP;
         my $left_score = $best_score_at_k[$k-1] + $GAP;

         if ($diag_score <= 0 && $up_score <= 0 && $left_score <= 0) {
            $best_score_at_k[$k] = 0;
            $best_paths_at_k[$k] = $empty;
            next;
         }

         my $new_score = 1;
         my @new_paths;
         if ($diag_score >= $new_score) {
            if ($diag_score > $new_score) {
               $new_score = $diag_score;
               @new_paths = ();
            }

            push @new_paths, map { $_ . "\3" } @{ $best_paths_at_k[$k] } ? @{ $best_paths_at_k[$k] } : pack('JJ', $i, $j);
         }

         if ($up_score >= $new_score) {
            if ($up_score > $new_score) {
               $new_score = $up_score;
               @new_paths = ();
            }

            # @{ $best_paths_at_k[$k+1] } will never be empty because a gap will never start a sequence.
            push @new_paths, map { $_ . "\1" } @{ $best_paths_at_k[$k+1] };
         }

         if ($left_score >= $new_score) {
            if ($left_score > $new_score) {
               $new_score = $left_score;
               @new_paths = ();
            }

            # @{ $best_paths_at_k[$k+1] } will never be empty because a gap will never start a sequence.
            push @new_paths, map { $_ . "\2" } @{ $best_paths_at_k[$k-1] };
         }

         $best_score_at_k[$k] = $new_score;
         $best_paths_at_k[$k] = \@new_paths;

         if ($new_score >= $best_score) {
            if ($new_score > $best_score) {
               $best_score = $new_score;
               @best_paths = ();
            }

            push @best_paths, @new_paths;
         }
      }
   }

   return
      map {
         my ($I, $J, @path) = unpack 'JJC*', $_;

         my ($align1, $align2);
         my $i = $I-1;
         my $j = $J-1;
         for (@path) {
            $align1 .= ( $_ & 1 ) ? $s[++$i] : '-';
            $align2 .= ( $_ & 2 ) ? $t[++$j] : '-';
         }

         [ $I, $align1, $J, $align2 ]
      }
         @best_paths;
}


die "usage\n" if @ARGV != 2;
say sprintf '%2$s (at pos %1$s) / %4$s (at pos %3$s)', @$_ for local_alignment(@ARGV);
```

Test:

```
$ ./local_alignment COELACANTH PELICAN
ELACAN (at pos 2) / ELICAN (at pos 1)

$ ./local_alignment COELACANTH PELICANPELICAN
ELACAN (at pos 2) / ELICAN (at pos 1)
ELACAN (at pos 2) / ELICAN (at pos 8)

$ ./local_alignment ABCE ABCDE
ABC (at pos 0) / ABC (at pos 0)
ABC-E (at pos 0) / ABCDE (at pos 0)

$ ./local_alignment ABCDE ABDCE
AB (at pos 0) / AB (at pos 0)
AB-C (at pos 0) / ABDC (at pos 0)
ABCD (at pos 0) / AB-D (at pos 0)
AB-CDE (at pos 0) / ABDC-E (at pos 0)
ABCD-E (at pos 0) / AB-DCE (at pos 0)
```